# Random Double Arc Endpoint Angles

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, random

I am trying to add some randomness to a double arc using `random steps`. The top and bottom endpoints of the arc are not at the same angles as the same arc drawn normally.

[image: Random double arc]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{rough/.style={decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=6pt}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[double distance=1cm, double=yellow, rough, color=red] (0,0) arc (0:90:3);
\draw[line width=0.01cm] (0,0) arc (0:90:3) -- (-3,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want the following angles at the endpoints, with `random steps` in between:

[image: smooth double arc]

How do I make the double arc's endpoints perfectly horizontal and vertical (preferably in a way that works with any amplitude and segment length)?

Comment: Draw little extra and Use `clip` to crop it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to draw little extra double arc and crop it using `clip`. In order to draw little longer double arc, polar coordinates are used.

```
\draw[double distance=1cm, double=yellow, rough, color=red] (-10:3) arc (-10:100:3);
```

A rectanglar cropping is done using `clip`.

```
\clip (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
```

[image]

See MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{rough/.style={decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=6pt}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-3cm] % <-added
\clip (0,0) rectangle (4,4); % <-added
\draw[double distance=1cm, double=yellow, rough, color=red] (-10:3) arc (-10:100:3);% <-changed
\end{scope}
\draw[line width=0.01cm] (0,0) arc (0:90:3) -- (-3,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### EDIT

Triangular clipping can be used for clipping other angle ranges.

Example:

```
\clip (0:0) -- (10:6) -- (80:6)--cycle;
```

and

```
\clip (0:0) -- (30:6) -- (60:6)--cycle;
```

produces following output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Is it possible to cleanly clip the arc in a way that works for other angle ranges (-30:30 degrees for example)?

Comment: @anonymous_pigeon yes. In that case clipping path has to be changed from `rectangle` to required shape (double arc).

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun: a reminder that one can switch on and off decorations along a path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{rough/.style={decoration={random steps,segment length=6pt}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,fill=yellow, rough] (0.5,0) decorate {arc (0:90:3.5)} 
 -- ++(0,-1) 
decorate {arc(90:0:2.5)} -- cycle ;
\draw[line width=0.01cm] (0,0) arc (0:90:3) -- (-3,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]